# How to pass OAuth1.0 as http parameter in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-8

A client sent me their `token_url`, `client_id`, `client_secret` which is used to perform `get` request from the `base_url`. I manually setup `OAuth1.0` using postman and I managed to get the data from the endpoint. Now, I want to write a code in laravel and pass on the `client_id` and `client_secret` to get the data from the enpoint. I tried the approach below but I'm getting `Unauthorized 401`. How to approach this? Thanks!

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$base_url = 'some_base_url';
$headers = [
    'client_id' => $client_id,
    'client_secret' => $client_secret
];

$response = Http::withHeaders($headers)->get($base_url);
dd($response);
```

Comment: which third Party are you accessing?

Comment: for now I'm not using any. just default laravel's http